# Приложение не сохраняет изменения в других Activity. Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

*.hi*

Прошу помощи. Есть небольшое приложение с 3 activity. Навигация между ними сделана onClick.
За первый заход были созданы активити, кнопки, их названия и взаимодействие между ними. Пользуюсь телефоном для проверки. Запустил на телефоне, все работало. Вышел. Через какое-то время вернулся, запустил проект, на одном из активити решил сделать выпадающий список, но изменения почему-то не принимаются в приложении. Если изменения делаются в MainActivity, то в приложении отображаются. А если в других, то изменений нет.
Полазил по гуглу. В разделе Run/Debug Configuration/Before Launch:/ стоит только Gradle-aware Make. Пните в нужное русло. Где лажаю?

Манифест

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> package="com.example.skljava">
>
> ```
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
>     android:supportsRtl="true"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>     <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity android:name=".SkladActivity"></activity>
>     <activity android:name=".PeopleActivity"></activity>
> </application>
> ```

МейнАктивити

> ```
> package com.example.skljava;
>
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
>
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         Button button_sklad = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sklad);
>         button_sklad.setOnClickListener(this);
>         Button button_people = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_people);
>         button_people.setOnClickListener(this);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view) {
>         Intent i;
>         i = new Intent(this, SkladActivity.class);
>         i = new Intent(this, PeopleActivity.class);
>         startActivity(i);
>     }
> }
> ```

SkladActivity

> package com.example.skljava;
>
> ```
> import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.widget.Button;
>
>
>
> public class SkladActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_sklad);
>         Button button_Back_Activity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Back_Activity);
>         button_Back_Activity.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View view) {
>         Intent i;
>         i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
>         startActivity(i);
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Build->Clean Project, File->Invalidate Cashe/Restart, File->SyncProject